# How to export or share Google+ photos with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-plus

There must be an easier way to do this than re-upping hundreds of photos all over again? I have tried everything I can find in Facebook apps and an iOS app called Facebook Photo Importer which looks the part but crashes every 2 mins!

Answer (score 1):

[Social Photos](http://socialphotos.net/) is a nice online program to do that.